# Find the value of 'x'

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

What is the value of x, if:
$$(\log_{10} 4 )^2 +  (\log_{10} 4 )^4+ (\log_{10} 4 )^{16}+ (\log_{10} 4 )^x = 6? $$

Answer (score 3):

$$(\log_{10} 4 )^x = 6-((\log_{10} 4 )^2 +  (\log_{10} 4 )^4+ (\log_{10} 4 )^{16})$$ then $$ x =\log_{\log_{10} 4} (6-((\log_{10} 4 )^2 +  (\log_{10} 4 )^4+ (\log_{10} 4 )^{16}))$$

Because $0 < \log_{10} 4 < 1$ the expression above is correctly defined.